# Re-entering Israel as a tourist after student visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, israel

My husband and I are British nationals living in Israel with student and spouse visas. Our visas expire on 3rd December 2014, and we have been unable to get an appointment to renew them before January 2015.

We want to go home for Christmas to UK  and return to Israel in January, at which time our resident visas will have expired.

Are we likely to be able to re-enter Israel on the normal 90 day tourist visa exemption, and then renew our other visas or is that going to cause problems with us coming back into Israel?

Comment: Whichever of you is the student should be able to get advice on this from the place you're studying: they'll be used to dealing with visa issues for foreign students.

Comment: The case 15 years ago (it may have changed) was that it was easier to get a student visa with proof of enrollment _before_ leaving the United States and I would expect the UK to be similar. Why don't you see if a Christmas-time appointment is available in London?